# Computer Telephony Integration with Web application

Tags: web-applications, adapter, integration, telephony

I am trying to integrate call support with my business web application. I am starting from scratch. I would be very glad if someone can point out to any resources that might help me in this endeavor. Also if someone can enlighten with the architecture, the libraries that i will need to use, the approach i will need to take, if there is any sample project etc etc. Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

I am aware that sales force has something called open cti(i didnt explore much), but I would like to implement or at least try to write everything on my own. Is it feasible and recommended.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Open CTI is just an API which consist of different behavioural javascript functions(So if you want to make your own then you can customise soft phones according to your convenience). If you want to build customise functionalities Open CTI giving option for custom functionality using SOAP API etc.
I referred this doc for reference,
[OPEN CTI DEVELOPER GUIDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_intro.htm)

Comment: I think JavaScript will be extremely useful with web sockets to handle call events(if you want to make it your own)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very open question. What phone system are you looking to support? What platform is your business application based? If it is truly green field, Twilio would be an excellent place to start and they provide sample code (in multiple languages) that will have you up and running with a telephony client embedded in a web page in no time.

Salesforce OpenCTI is a framework that allows you to design a web app (hosted in SFDC iFrame) to link a premise or cloud telephony system with Salesforce. This could be relevant if your business app runs in Salesforce. You can build a Salesforce CTI integration outside of OpenCTI, but this is the simplest path forward. There are several github projects dedicated to this.

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-salesforce

If you want to provide a few more details I can get you pointed in the right direction. It is feasible, and complexity depends more on the phone system, but I can't recommend an approach without understanding the existing components you have to work with.